# MinimumShouldMatch not appending to "Should" clause in a Bool query built using object initializer syntax in Nest ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core, nest

I am using the NEST object initializer syntax to build my queries dynamically given user input. The query format I am using is like this:

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "range": {
                    "field1": {
                        "lt": x
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "range": {
                    "field2": {
                        "lt": y
                    }
                }
            }],
            "filter": [{
                ...
            }]
        }
    }
```

The above query doesn't work because the should is overridden by the filter unless the should clause has a "minimum_should_match" field attached to it, like so:

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "range": {
                    "field1": {
                        "lt": x
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "range": {
                    "field2": {
                        "lt": y
                    }
                }
            }],
            "minimum_should_match" = "1",
            "filter": [{
                ...
            }]
        }
    }
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to position the minimum_should_match clause correctly so that it sits in between the should and filter. The BoolQuery accepts a "MinimumShouldMatch" field, but that appends it after the filter and not before the should.

Is there a way to do this or I am going to have to use raw search input?

Comment: Can you update your question to provide the code you're using to construct the `bool` query? In JSON, the order of object properties does not matter and cannot be relied upon, so it doesn't matter where the `"minimum_should_match"` property appears inside the `"bool": {}` object

Comment: You are indeed correct, the positioning of the "minimum_should_match" clause does not matter. I made a mistake in my testing that made me think that the filter was being overridden and I had wrongly assumed that the positioning was the issue. I went back and re-tested my query and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment by Russ Cam, the positioning of the "minimum_should_match" clause does not matter. I made a mistake in my testing that made my thinking the filter was being overridden, and I had wrongly assumed the positioning was the issue. I went and retested the query and it works correctly.